# Install MongoDB without YUM on Linux RHEL 6.7

Tags: linux, mongodb, rhel6

I have have a Linux machine that I am trying to install MongoDB on. Unfortunately for me my work limits external access from where this machine is located at. I have tried to follow MongoDb's documentation on how to install via setting up YUM repo, but due to my machine having limited external access I can't install the way the documentation suggest since I cant reach the following site.

this is where to point mongodb yum repo.
https://repo.mongodb.com/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-enterprise/3.4/$basearch/

I wanted to know if anyone knows another way of possibly installing MongoDB? I have other machines that I could possibly use to download RPM's if they exist.

Also I should mention I am running the following OS

cat /etc/*release

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.7 (Santiago)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.7 (Santiago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have waited a little longer before posting this question but I basically found in the documentation on how to install via tar ball. The steps are found here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/